# Show that $f$ is a polynomial if it's the uniform limit of polynomais

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function which is the uniform limit of polynomials. I want to show that $f$ is a polynomial.

I mean this seems a bit trivial... 
If it's the uniform limit of the set of polynomials doesn't that guarantee it's a polynomial?

If I define $f$ to be the set of all polynomial do I define a uniform limit $L$ s.t $d(f,L)<\epsilon$?  or approach via contradiction?

any help would be great

Comment: It seems trivial if you think about it in the right way. However, $\sin x$ is a limit of polynomials and that is not a finite polynomial.

Comment: **Any** continuous function on a closed bounded (thus, compact) interval is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials. Thus, the claim you try to prove is false, @user164587

Comment: How do you know how to define a limit of polynomials? Is there a different way to phrase this that would make it easier to understand?

Comment: @Timbuc The point is that this is on all of $\mathbb R$, not on a compact interval.

Comment: I see , @Robert.

Comment: @user146296 I would like to know where to find this exercise since I am studying this subject.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca This is late, but for future readers this is from Marsden **Elementary Classical Analysis** 2'nd ed., pg 322, exercise 50

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: if $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $f$ is unbounded.  What does this say about $f_n(z) - f_m(z)$, if $f_n$ is a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: If fn and fm are both sequences of polynomials then the difference will be a polynomial right.  I guess I'm struggling with writing up a proof for this.

Comment: @leo We don't know yet that $f(z)$ is a polynomial.  That's what we're trying to prove.

Comment: @user146296 It's just one sequence of polynomials, not two.  $f_n$ and $f_m$ are two members of the sequence.  If it converges uniformly, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for all $m$ and $n$ both $> N$, ...

Comment: You are right. ${}$

Comment: So if I have |fn-fm| and fix n and let m got to infinity the fm=Limit.  And if I supposed the Limit to be sinx then I get  fn-sinx.  Am I on the  right track..? any more help and reasoning would really help me

Comment: The point is that if the sequence converges uniformly, and $m$ is large enough, then $|f_n - f_m|$ is uniformly bounded for $n > m$, and since $f_n - f_m$ is a polynomial this implies that $f_n - f_m$ is a constant function.  **Now** you take the limit as $n \to \infty$, and find that $f = f_m + \text{constant}$, which is a polynomial.